# Hash change in browser history with Laravel / Inertia Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm building a form with Inertia/ Vue.js that is split in multiple tabs.

I would like that clicking on a tab changes the current hash in history so the user is redirected to the current tab after refreshing the page.

The first solution I thought about was to simply use `history.replaceState()` when clicking on a tab:

```js
history.replaceState(null, '', `#${selectedTab.slug}`)
```

The problem is that Inertia keeps its own state in memory and as soon as I change a value in the form the hash is changed back to its original state.

The second solution I thought about was using Inertia's `router` but it makes an unnecessary request to the server.

```js
router.visit(`#${selectedTab.slug}`, {
  preserveScroll: true,
  preserveState: true,
  replace: true,
})
```

Is there any way to tell Inertia to change **only** the URL in the state object?

Comment: Sadly I didn't :(